# recenter the form after altering form size

Tags: delphi, resize

I have a combobox that has two options and the two options are triggering the form resizing. The idea is I'm going to hide and show additional controls based on the selection.

When I change the form width, the size changes as desired, however the form is now no longer in the center of the screen. Can I move the form's XY position back and forth while changing the form width?

```
procedure TReportFrm.SpecialFilesComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(SpecialFilesComboBox.ItemIndex = 0) then begin
    //No special files
    Width := 412;
    Height := 423;
    ...
  end
  else begin
    //Yes special files
    Width := 893;
    Height := 423;
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Comment: PS I cannot simple call out this after the `if` statement, I'll get an access violation: `BugReportFrm.Position := poMainFormCenter;`

Comment: is BugReportFrm assigned? Your code is showing TReportFrm. Just don't use an instance: Position := poMainFormCenter;

Comment: Just set `Top` and `Left` as required. Calculate from Monitor.WorkAreaRect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple ReCenter function may look like this:

```
procedure TReportFrm.ReCenter;
var
  LRect: TRect;
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  LRect := Screen.WorkAreaRect;
  X := LRect.Left + (LRect.Right - LRect.Left - Width) div 2;
  Y := LRect.Top + (LRect.Bottom - LRect.Top - Height) div 2;
  SetBounds(X, Y, Width, Height);
end;

procedure TReportFrm.SpecialFilesComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(SpecialFilesComboBox.ItemIndex = 0) then begin
    //No special files
    Width := 412;
    Height := 423;
    ...
  end
  else begin
    //Yes special files
    Width := 893;
    Height := 423;
    ...
  end;
  ReCenter;
end;
```

It centers the window to the WorkArea of the screen, you may want to center it to other reference, in that case it's up to you to determine the meaningful rectangle.

Comment: perfect. best/most straight forward delphi solution i've gotten in a while, thanks.

Comment: This maths are wrong here. They only work if work area top and left are both zero. Centre of work area is (Left+Right) div 2. Your minus sign is just wrong. The code also denies the existence of multi-monitor systems.

Comment: @David Oh my... I'm not sure if Screen can have different left/top than 0,0, but I updated my answer. As stated, it centers the form to the screen Workarea, and greatly you show how to get the WorkArea for the form monitor in your answer. I disagree with the (Left + Right) div 2 solution you propose, are you really sure of that? I have no other monitor at hand to test.

Comment: You fixed the maths error, but in a somewhat confused way. No need to mention Left twice.

Comment: @David you're right, but my brain like to see it that way at this time. :D

Comment: @David you're right, I posted that in my previous comment while you're writing yours.

Comment: The way to think about it is that you need to set the form's `Left` to `MonitorHCenter-HalfFormWidth`. With that viewpoint is becomes clear.

Answer (score 7):

Multi-monitor systems are common nowadays. Placing at the centre of the screen may spread the form across multiple monitors. That's undesirable.

So I'd centre the form on its monitor:

```
R := Form.Monitor.WorkAreaRect;
Form.Left := (R.Left+R.Right-Form.Width) div 2;
Form.Top := (R.Top+R.Bottom-Form.Height) div 2;
```

As @bummi points out, you can write:

```
Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
```

This almost works as you would wish. I will center the form on a screen. However, it always picks the default monitor. So using that code could result in your form being moved onto a different monitor which I think would never be desirable.

Rather forcing the form to the centre, you may decide instead to grow or shrink it on all sides:

```
procedure TReportFrm.SpecialFilesComboBoxChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewLeft, NewTop, NewWidth, NewHeight: Integer;
begin
  if(SpecialFilesComboBox.ItemIndex = 0) then begin
    //No special files
    NewWidth := 412;
    NewHeight := 423;
    ...
  end
  else begin
    //Yes special files
    NewWidth := 893;
    NewHeight := 423;
    ...
  end;

  NewLeft := Left + (Width-NewWidth) div 2;
  NewTop := Top + (Top-NewHeight) div 2;
  NewBoundsRect := Rect(NewLeft, NewTop, NewLeft+NewWidth, NewTop+NewHeight);
  BoundsRect := NewBoundsRect;
end;
```

And if you wanted to get really cute you'd adjust the bounds rect so that the newly sized and positioned form did not go off the edge of the monitor.

```
procedure MakeAppearOnScreen(var Rect: TRect);
const
  Padding = 24;
var
  Monitor: HMonitor;
  MonInfo: TMonitorInfo;
  Excess, Width, Height: Integer;
begin
  Monitor := MonitorFromPoint(Point((Rect.Left+Rect.Right) div 2, (Rect.Top+Rect.Bottom) div 2), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
  if Monitor=0 then begin
    exit;
  end;
  MonInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(MonInfo);
  if not GetMonitorInfo(Monitor, @MonInfo) then begin
    exit;
  end;
  Width := Rect.Right-Rect.Left;
  Height := Rect.Bottom-Rect.Top;

  Excess := Rect.Right+Padding-MonInfo.rcWork.Right;
  if Excess>0 then begin
    dec(Rect.Left, Excess);
  end;
  Excess := Rect.Bottom+Padding-MonInfo.rcWork.Bottom;
  if Excess>0 then begin
    dec(Rect.Top, Excess);
  end;
  Excess := MonInfo.rcWork.Left+Padding-Rect.Left;
  if Excess>0 then begin
    inc(Rect.Left, Excess);
  end;
  Excess := MonInfo.rcWork.Top+Padding-Rect.Top;
  if Excess>0 then begin
    inc(Rect.Top, Excess);
  end;
  Rect.Right := Rect.Left+Width;
  Rect.Bottom := Rect.Top+Height;
end;
```

Then the previous code sample would be altered like this:

```
NewBoundsRect := Rect(NewLeft, NewTop, NewLeft+NewWidth, NewTop+NewHeight);
MakeAppearOnScreen(NewBoundsRect);
BoundsRect := NewBoundsRect;
```

Comment: as far as Position will work as desired for different settings, I dont see the need for reemplementing.

Comment: @bummi Position only applies to the initial showing of the form I think.

Comment: I can't talk about Versions prior D7 , but this will work:  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Position := poScreenCenter;
end;

Comment: @bummi Thanks for that. I did not know that. Sadly `poScreenCenter` doesn't seem to work well with multi-monitor setups.

Comment: Just (re)setting Self.Position to Self.Position seems to work fine on XE2 with two monitors

Comment: @GerryColl Er, what do you mean. After the form is shown `Position` is changed to `poDesigned` to avoid a future window re-creation moving the form.

Comment: Sorry, I meant whatever position it was in the DFM, e.g. poMainFormCenter

Comment: @GerryColl If you use `poScreenCenter` it moves the form back to the primary monitor. Which seems wrong.

Comment: I hate jumping windows. IMHO, enforcing a window to be in the bounds of its monitor's working area once it is resized is quite enough (last part of the answer).